# Is there a way to hide decimals after a certain value in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, spreadsheet

In a Google Spreadsheet, I have a price for stocks displaying. I would like to remove the decimals if the price is over $1,000. I am half way there using MROUND function and TEXT function:

`=iferror(TEXT(IF(googlefinance(B2,"price")<1000,googlefinance(B2,"price"),MROUND(googlefinance(B2,"price"),1)),"$###,###.##"))`

I still get the .00 at the end, or just a . for companies over $1,000. Any way anyone knows to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `TEXT` function, how’s applying this custom number format?

`[>1000]$#;[<=1000]$###,###.00`

To apply a custom number format:

1. Select the cells you want to apply it to.
2. Format > Number > Custom number format
3. Enter the format in the input field and click Apply.

More on the custom number format:

- [A Complete Guide To The Google Sheets Custom Number Format](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheets-custom-number-format/)